# phpmyadmin  не хочет авторизоваться

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Возникла на днях проблема с `phpmyadmin`. Причем явилась она нежданно и неожиданно. При авторизации выскакивает ошибка размещенная внизу авторизации окна:

> "Не удалось установить подключение по
> параметрам определенных в секции
> controluser в конфигурационном файле
> config.inc.php"

И еще одна ошибка возникает одновременно вверху авторизации окна:

> 1045 невозможно подключиться к серверу
> mysql

Извините, но скриншот приложить, к сожалению, не могу.

Секция `Controluser` выгдядит вот так:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] =
> $dbuser;

Очевидно что эта переменная должна быть где то определенна. Поэтому решил поискать файл config.inc.php по системе. В результате поиска появились два файла:

Один находится по пути /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php. Это как раз таки тот файл в котором находится выше сказанное

Второй: /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php. абсолютно пустой.

Сам файл я прилагаю:

<a href='http://exfile.ru/357548'>Скачать config.inc.php с [exfile.ru](http://exfile.ru)</a>

Пытался на место переменной $dbuser прописать 'root'. Но и так ничего никаких результатов.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, что вы поставили phpmyadmin, как пакет в Debian (или Ubuntu).
В этом случае, переменная $dbuser и другие переменные прописаны в файле /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php. Соответственно, вам нужно убедиться, что у вас есть БД, с доступом через логин и пароль, указанные в этом файле.

Если вам не нужна служебная БД phpmyadmin (или вы не хотите её создавать), то файл /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php нужно очистить.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, но наверное проблема с самим сервером базы данных Mysql. У вас сайт есть? Если нет, попробуйте написать скрипт такой.

```
<?php 
$a = mysql_connect('localhost', '**root**', '**1234**') or die('Доступ к базе данных нет.');
?>
```

Не забудьте поменять, то что выделено жирным шрифтом на свои данные.
Если у Вас  на этой базе работает сайт и все хорошо, тогда напишите и будем дальше искать проблему.

Comment: Нет, сайта нет. Я просто хочу подключится к базе данных и все.

Comment: Попробуйте мой скрипт который вам написал то что в ** исправьте под свои. Если я не ошибаюсь, то у Вас сервер отключен. У вас хостинг или локальная машина?

Comment: Локальная машина, причем на linux. А где скрипт прописывать?

Comment: создайте файл например 1.php, с содержанием моего скрипта, и запустите его через браузер http://127.0.0.1/1.php

Answer (score 0):

А у вас вообще работал `phpmyadmin`?
Просто если вы его только пытаетесь запустить - вам нужно сервер баз данных запустить, базу создать и указать в конфиг пхпмайадмина.

Ошибка "1045 невозможно подключиться к серверу mysql" возникает в случае, если не правильно указан адрес сервера бд, не правильный логин или пароль.

Других причин не знаю.